# Как спарсить строки из html файла на php?

Tags: php, html

Всем доброй ночи Есть текстовый документ .txt в котором с новой строки написаны фразы, и есть html документ, где с новой строки идет код + фразы из списка. Строк в html порядка 1000, возможно ли, спарсить все строки из html, в которых есть совпадения с .txt. Фразы в html и txt используются по 1 разу, т.е не повторяются.

Пример строк .txt:

- Фраза 1
- Фраза 2
- Фраза 3
- Новая фраза

Пример строк в html

```
<tr><td></td><td></td><td>Фраза 3</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td>Этой фразы нет</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td>Фраза 1</td><td></td></tr>
```

Получается что в 3 ячейке встречается фраза, а в остальных - произвольные данные

За ранее спасибо.

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть пример - несколько строк из .txt и несколько строк из HTML

Comment: Добавила примеры строк

Comment: Возможно, с помощью html-парсера

Comment: на каком именно моменте проблема-то возникает? [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php) может вам помочь удалить лишнее из html, для дальнейшего сравнения. У этого html есть еще что-либо кроме указанных строк, или это чисто файл с такими строками?

Comment: В этом месте есть контент <td></td><td></td><td></td>, а так - файл чисто с этими строками. Проблема возникает в написании парсера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выполнения данной задачи вам, очевидно, для начала потребуется получить данные из обоих файлов. Сделать это можно с помощью функции [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php), которая возвращает массив строк из файла. С помощью флага `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` можно исключить символ конца строки `\n` из элементов массива.

Дальнейший алгоритм можно строить по разному, исходя из потребностей в эффективности. В любом случае у нас будет цикл по строкам html-файла, внутри которого необходимо определить, встречается ли такая строка в текстовом файле. В самом простом случае для этого нам потребуется вложенный цикл для проверки строк. Если необходимо повысить эффективность, то можно сортировать список строк и использовать бинарный поиск.

Разбить исходную html-строку и вытащить из нее содержимое последней ячейки можно, несколькими путями. Наиболее простыми будет использование функции [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php), либо с помощью регулярных выражений. Разделителем для `explode()` будет `</td><td>`. В результате чего в последнем 4-м элементе массива получим искомую строку, оканчивающуюся на `</td></tr>`. Эти символы, в свою очередь, можно либо просто убрать с помощью [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php), либо заменить через [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php), либо убрать, используя [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stip-tags.php).

Во вложенном цикле сравнения строк, если совпадение найдено, то исходную html-строку добавляем в массив результатов, а найденную исходную текстовую строку удаляем из массива строк, т.к. больше она нам, согласно условию, не встретится.

Исходя из вышенаписанного, код решения задачи имеет следующий вид:

```
$strings = file("strings.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$html = file("data.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$result = [];

foreach($html as $row){
    $value = array_pop(explode("</td><td>", $row, 4));
    $value = substr($value, 0, -10);     // удалить </td></tr>

    foreach($strings as $k => $str){
        if($str == $value){
            $result[] = $row;
            unset($strings[$k]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ и код решения. Торопилась, и написала не ту конструкцию. Фраза находится в 3 ячейке, а в 1,2 и 4 - произвольный текст

Comment: @Eva_m это в целом упрощает задачу, просто надо брать не последний элемент после `explode` и потом обрезать конец, а просто брать 3й: `$value = explode("</td><td>", $row, 4)[2];` а следующая строка с `substr` не нужа

Comment: флаг `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` в таком случае тоже не нужен.

Comment: По какой то причине, пишет ошибку в этой строке `Undefined offset: 2 in`

Comment: @Eva_m в какой этой? можно попробоватаь вариант записи `list(,,$value) = explode("</td><td>", $row, 4);` но убедитесь, что `explode()` вообще правильно разбивает строку.

Comment: и эта `$value = explode("</td><td>", $row, 4)[2];` и эта `list(,,$value) = explode("</td><td>", $row, 4);` выдают ошибку **Notice: Undefined offset: 2** А как проверить explode() на корректность? И что странно, ошибку пишет 3 раза подряд - после чего, ниже, выводит 1 результат

Comment: Обратно добавила `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` и все стало работать. Большое вам спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: @Eva_m да, мой косяк, в файле строк убирать `IGNORE_NEW_LINES` не надо было, конечно.